# NEUTRAL GEOMETRY PROOF. prove that a figure can have at most one center of symmetry

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

A center of symmetry for a figure F is a point O such that every line through it cuts F in two points, P and P', such that O is the midpoint of PP'. Prove that a figure can have at most one center of symmetry.

I have no clue how to prove this! any help will be much apprecitated

Comment: Suppose $O$ and $O'$ are two such points. Consider the line that goes through both of them.

Comment: @JohnDouma: I think that comment would be a good answer.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean please? I'm terrible at this geometry and having trouble catching up

Answer (score 0):

Let $O$ and $O'$ be two points with the properties that define a center of symmetry. Let $L$ be the line that goes through both $O$ and $O'$. Then $L$ cuts $F$ in two points $P$ and $P'$ and both $O$ and $O'$ must be the midpoint of the segment defined by $P$ and $P'$.

Therefore, $O=O'$.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. Will proving O = O' be sufficient enough as a proof? Sorry I'm new to proofs.

Comment: Yes. You are trying to prove you can have at most one center of symmetry. This says that if you have more than one they must be the same. Note: neither this proof nor the statement says there has to be one. We are just saying that there can be at most one.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the statement is false. Consider two distinct parallel lines in the plane. There are infinitely many points $O$ such that $O$ is a center of symmetry. The proof given as an answer assumes that the line passing through $OO'$ always intersects the figure. The correctly worded question is

Prove that any connected, closed figure has at most one center of symmetry.