# Do there exist geometric figures with multiple centers of symmetry?

Tags: geometry

> Do there exist geometric figures with multiple centers of symmetry? Under what conditions does the center symmetry lie inside a geometric figure?

Recall the definition of a center of symmetry: A center of symmetry $O$ of a closed figure $\mathcal{F}$ is a point such that for any $X,Y$ on $\mathcal{F}$ with $X,O,Y$ collinear, $OX = OY$.

It would make sense that there are figures with multiple centers of symmetry, but I didn't think of any. Also, I conjecture that the center of symmetry always lies inside a convex geometric figure unless that figure is a point. This is obviously not true for nonconvex.

Comment: So according to this definition a disc has no center of symmetry?

Comment: @HenningMakholm If by disc you mean open disc then yes.

Comment: x @user: Open or closed, that doesn't seem to matter. No figure with nonempty interior will qualify.

Comment: @HenningMakholm A closed disc of radius $1$ has a center of symmetry, right?

Comment: I think what @HenningMakholm is getting at is that the definition should probably be: "A centre of symmetry $O$ of a figure $\mathcal F$ is a point such that for any $X \neq O$ on $\mathcal F$, there exists a $Y \neq X$ on $\mathcal F$ with $X,O,Y$ collinear and $OX=OY$."

Comment: x @user: Where would that be? No matter what you declare to be $O$, the line through $O$ and the center of the disc will contain points on that have different distances to $O$. (The possible distances will form an interval of length between $1$ and $2$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm My definition says take any line that passes through $O$ and intersects $\mathcal{F}$ at distinct points $X,Y$. Then $O$ is a center of symmetry if $OX = OY$ for all lines.

Comment: @user19405892: And an open or closed disc cannot possibly satisfy that definition for any $O$. No matter where you put $O$ there will be $X,Y$ in the disc such that $|OX|\ne|OY|$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I agree, but I am saying that $X,O,Y$ are collinear.

Comment: @user19405892: Consider the closed unit disc $\{(x,y)\mid \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le 1\}$. Which point in the plane would you say is a "center of symmetry" according to your definition?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Any line that passes through the center of a closed unit disc of radius $4$ will intersect the circle at two distinct points $X,Y$ such that $OX = OY$. Thus $O$ is a center of symmetry.

Comment: @user19405892: A _unit_ disc, by definition, has radius $1$, not $4$. But never mind that -- should I understand that you're claiming that $(0,0)$ is a "center of symmetry" of the above unit disc according to your definition? It is not -- because, for example, you could take $X=(0,\frac12)$ and $Y=(0,\frac13)$. These $X$ and $Y$ are both in the unit disc; they are collinear with $(0,0)$, but they don't have the same distance to $(0,0)$. Note that your definition is not saying that there _exist_ equidistant $X,Y$ on every line, but that _every collinear_ $X,Y$ must be equidistant.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah! I see the confusion. I meant by "on" in my definition by on the boundary and not inside.

Comment: @user19405892: A figure consisting only of the perimeter and not the inside is called a "circle", not a "disc".

Comment: @HenningMakholm That's right. I was referring to the boundary of the disc.

Comment: It seems to me that under this definition the typical 5-pointed star wouldn't have a center of symmetry. Is this correct, or am I missing something? (Did you get this definition from somewhere, by the way? Or is it *your* attempt to define a center of symmetry?)

Comment: But **I'm** referring to the entire disc and pointing out that according to your definition it does not have any center of symmetry -- which, to me, means that you definition of "center of symmetry" does not come even close to capturing the intuitive meaning of those words. I really think you ought to switch to the alternative definition @Théophile proposed.

Comment: @HenningMakholm disc doesn't have a center of symmetry, though, since it doesn't have a boundary. The mathematical definition I have presented above of a center of symmetry is an equivalent way of saying "A point, within an object or figure, through which any straight line also passes through two points on the edge of the figure at the same distance from the centre but on opposite sides."

Comment: @user19405892: A definition of "center of symmetry" that does not allow a disc to have a center of symmetry is an awful definition that does not at all define what those words mean in usual mathematical discourse, and you should be doing everyone you aspire to communicate with a favor and not use such an awful definition. If you _must_ use the concept you're defining here, call it something else than "center of symmetry".

Comment: @HenningMakholm In Euclidean geometry, I believe the definition I was using the accepted definition and the fact that a disc doesn't have a center of symmetry follows from that. However, if you are using the definition of center of symmetry outside of geometry I would agree we should expand the definition.

Comment: @user19405892: In Euclidean geometry, I don't know _anyone_ who would accept a definition of "center of symmetry" that doesn't make the center of a disc its center of symmetry. Such a definition is most certainly not "accepted" in general (except, apparently, by you -- for reasons that I can't fathom).

Comment: @HenningMakholm All the definitions online seem to say "boundary" and that's why I am thinking that a disc doesn't have a center of symmetry. But maybe because of the lack of definitions I see you may be right.

Comment: Do you consider a straight line being closed? It doesn't have a boundary but no one would say that it's not.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Also, there are other problems on this site that use my same definition: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707903/neutral-geometry-proof-prove-that-a-figure-can-have-at-most-one-center-of-symme?rq=1

Comment: [Infinite honeycomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_tiling) has infinitely many centers of symmetry.

Comment: @user19405892 Interesting. Note that the definition in your link you referred to is slightly different: it's saying that there *will* be two points $X,Y$ on any given line through $O$. The definition you wrote yourself says that *if* there is a point $X$, then there will be a point $Y$ such that $X,Y,O$ are collinear. This means that, for example, an ellipse would have a centre of symmetry in both definitions; the six points of a regular hexagon would have a centre of symmetry in your definition but not the other; and the five points of a regular pentagon would not have a centre in either.

Comment: @user19405892 At this point, though, since the definitions are so strange, it might help if you told us what a "figure" is, since I'm guessing it has a precise meaning in your context.

Answer (score 1):

A figure consisting of two (sufficiently close) parallel segments has infinitely many centers of symmetry. Or consider two parallel plates. If the figure has to be connected, then connect a pair of corresponding ends to make a rectangular 'C' shape (you might need to adjust dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

Are you restricting yourself to 2D?

A cube has a centre of symmetry at every vertex.

All of the platonic solids have multiple centres of symmetry.